# how to create a traffic light system in react native for mobile using javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, timer

how can I create a traffic light program in react native by using simple `<Text>` just to show light color and I want to use `setInterval` as the timer concept? Thanks in advance.

```
`setYellow=()=>{
return(<View>
<Text style={{color:'yellow'}}>YELLOW</Text>
</View>)
}

setGreen=()=>{
return(<View>
<Text style={{color:'green'}}>YELLOW</Text>
</View>)
}`

and I am writing in return this way:
`let time=0;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{color:'red'}}>
      {time==0?'RED':
      this.setYellow()}
      </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );`
```

but I am not able to get the exact logic. How can I write my Text from `'react-native'` with colors inside the render return method to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about states, you need to use the `useState()` hook.

```js
const App = () => {
    const trafficLight = [
        {color: 'red', text: 'RED'},
        {color: 'yellow', text: 'YELLOW'},
        {color: 'green', text: 'GREEN'},
    ];

    const [light, setLight] = useState(0);
    let currentLight = light;

    setInterval(() => {
        if(currentLight > 2) {
            setLight(0);
            currentLight = 0:
        } else {
            setLight(currentLight);
            currentLight++;
        }
    }, 1000);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style = {{styles.container}}>
            <Text style={{color: trafficLight[light].color}}>
                {trafficLight[light].text}
            </Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};
```

And also I added `currentLight`, because I can't check how `useState(light++)` would work. If it set light to current value, and then implement it, you don't need `currentLight`.